# autorelease problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why the NSArray allocated with arrayWithObjects dealloc automatically if already used by BObject object?? in teory NSArray must remain allocated all the BObject life time...

```
[[BObject alloc] initObjectName:@"oneObject" states:
   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [[State alloc] initStateName:@"stand_front" singleImg:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"front_1.png"], nil]],
    [[State alloc] initStateName:@"front_walking" frames:
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"front_1.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"front_2.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"front_3.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"front_4.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"front_5.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"front_6.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"front_7.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"front_8.png"], 
      nil] duration:0.8 repeat:0],
    nil]
   isSolid:TRUE];
```

Comment: What is a "BObject", and does it retain the `states:` parameter?

Comment: no, it don't retain the states... i've patched.. thx :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BObject must retain the array passed as `states:`

Answer (score 0):

The `BObject` probably makes a copy of the array, instead of retaining it.